# How to access member variable in boost lambda expression?

Tags: c++, boost, lambda

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::lambda;
using namespace boost::multi_index;
using boost::multi_index_container;
using boost::lexical_cast;

struct student {
    int no;
    string name;
    student(int _no, string _name) : no(_no), name(_name)  { }
};

struct no {};
struct name {};

struct change_name {
    change_name(const string& new_namex) : new_name(new_namex) {}
    void operator()(student& stu) {
        stu.name = new_name;
    }
    private:
    string new_name;
};

int main()
{
    typedef multi_index_container< 
        student,
        indexed_by<
            ordered_non_unique<tag<no>, member<student, int, &student::no>>,
            ordered_non_unique<tag<name>, member<student, string, &student::name>>
        >> student_set;

    typedef student_set::index<no>::type student_set_no;

    student_set students;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) 
        students.insert( student(i, "love student " + lexical_cast<string>(i)) );
    student_set_no& no_index = students.get<no>();
    student_set_no::iterator iter = no_index.find(3);

    //suppose i want to change the name to "you",
    no_index.modify(iter, change_name("you"));
    //how could i do this with lambda expression ?
    no_index.modify(iter, _1.name = "you");

    cout << iter->name << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

How could I change the name without defined the function operator class?

Thanks.

Comment: This is really tricky. Boost.Lambda data member access doesn't work well with references and you would need to nest three functors (address of, dereference and assignment). You should have a look at Boost.Phoenix, which supersedes Boost.Lambda. Or get a C++11 compiler and be done with this.

Comment: how could a c++ 11 compiler help, could you provide more details.

Comment: It provides lambda expressions, which make a lot of the pain go away.

Comment: How could it help of this particular problem?

Comment: `modify(iter, [](student& s) { s.name = "you" });`

Comment: @pmr:could you please  add the tricky boost.lambda solution and this lambda expression as answer. thx.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13106/discussion-between-jichao-and-pmr)